# Can we have our profile's descriptions synced?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I was just editing my profile, adding a link to my blog, which I just started. I was hoping that it'd be unified across all of the sites I have an account on, especially since it is using the OpenID system. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 10):

There is a "Copy  Profile To Related Accounts" button on the `accounts` tab of your user profile page. If you use that, you can copy your profile to all sites.

For some users, they might want to include different information on different sites, often themed to the specific topic of the site. So automatic syncing is not really a favorable idea. But the aformentioned button should do the trick you need.

Comment: guess things changed since this answer, found the button when editing a profile, under the save button